# When creating a view how do I separate one column into two depending on a foreign key value?

Tags: mysql

I'm supposed to create a view that joins the Customer table with the Address table and Address type table. Call it Customer_View.  Have two sections for the Address; Physical and Mailing. Make sure that your column headings reflect the two sections. If they are both you can just put the details under the Physical.

---

***These are my tables with columns***

**Customers**
Columns:
Customer_Id
Last_Name
First_Name
Middle_Name 
Phone
Email

---

**Address**
Columns:
Address_Id
Customer_Id
Address_Type_Id 
Address_1 
Address_2
City
State
Zip
Country

---

**address_type**
Columns:
Address_Type_Id 
Description

---

I know how to join the tables but I don't know how to make it so the address column shows as two columns, one for physical and one for mailing, depending on if the address_type_id value is *1* & *3* or *2*... does that make sense?

---

This is the code I have:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Customer_View AS
SELECT  c.customer_id, CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
        Address_1, Address_2, Phone, Email, City, State, Zip, Country,
FROM address AS a
    JOIN customer AS c
        ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id
    JOIN address_type AS aty
        ON a.address_type_id = atp.address_type_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use CASE construction in the query SELECT list:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN aty.address_type_id IN (1,3) THEN a.Address1 ELSE NULL END as mail_address,
   CASE 
      WHEN aty.address_type_id =2 THEN a.Address1 ELSE NULL END as physical_address
....
FROM ...
```